# Laravel Shopify API returns Required parameter missing or invalid on POST Request

Tags: laravel, api, shopify

I am using Osiset's github for laravel + shopify: https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify

But I don't seem the get the POST request going, tried all kinds of variantions already hope one of you'll see my mistake!

Code:

```
$order_array = [
    'order' => [
        'email' => "foo@example.com",
        'line_items' => [
             'variant_id' => 6103067132088,
             'quantity' => 1
        ]
    ]
];

$order_array = json_encode($order_array);
$shop = User::first();
$request = $shop->api()->rest('POST', '/admin/orders.json', ['body' => $order_array]);

dd($request['body']);
```

if I do a dd() on order_array after the encode it shows:

```
{"order":{"email":"foo@example.com","line_items":{"variant_id":6103067132088,"quantity":1}}}
```

And then it returns

```
array:1 [
"order" => "Required parameter missing or invalid"
]
```

I've also tried to make 'body' to 'query'...

Comment: First try to set `line_items` in double array since per [docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#create-2020-10) `line_items` is array of objects. Then repeat the same without `body` key.

Comment: It's what I am doing here right? The response is: {"order":{"email":"foo@example.com","line_items":{"variant_id":6103067132088,"quantity":1}}}

Comment: `'line_items' => [['variant_id' => 6103067132088, 'quantity' => 1], ['variant_id' => 6103067132089, 'quantity' => 2]]`

Comment: That doens't work either...I exactly copied your code to make sure: $order_array = [
            'order' => [
                'email' => "foo@example.com",
                'line_items' => [['variant_id' => 6103067132088, 'quantity' => 1], ['variant_id' => 6103067132089, 'quantity' => 2]]
            ]
        ];

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution!

// Replace rest

```
$request = $shop->api()->rest('POST', '/admin/orders.json', ['body' => $order_array]);
```

// With request

```
$request = $shop->api()->request('POST', '/admin/orders.json', $order_array);
```